# Zeroes of certain $L$-functions on the critical line and GGP conjectures

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, l-functions

Global Gan-Gross-Prasad conjecture (on various groups) says that nonvanishing of certain automorphic $L$-function $L(s, \pi)$ (of cuspidal representation $\pi$ of some reductive group $G$) at $s = 1/2$ is (roughly) equivalent to that the corresponding automorphic representation is distinguished by certain subgroup $H \leq G$, i.e. the automorphic period (integrate corresponding automorphic forms over the automorphic quotient of that subgroup)

$$
\mathcal{P}_H(\varphi) =\int_{[H]}\phi(h) \mathrm{d}h, \quad \varphi \in \pi
$$

is nonzero. In this line of thought, I wonder if we can say anything about the zeros of $L(s, \pi)$ on the critical line $\Re(s) = 1/2$ by analyzing periods $\mathcal{P}_H$ instead.
I feel like the $L$-value $L(1/2 + it, \pi)$ for $t \in \mathbb{R}$ should be related to the twisted periods

$$
\mathcal{P}_{H, |\cdot|^{it}}(\varphi) =\int_{[H]}\phi(h)|\det(h)|^{it} \mathrm{d}h
$$

and say something about vanishing of this period in terms of representation theory, for example. Especially, I wonder if there's any work in this line to show that there are infinitely many (or even quantify them in a certain sense, e.g. find asymptotes or lower/uppoer bounds for the number of zeros with $|t| \leq T$ in terms of $T$), by analyzing periods instead.

Comment: If this were true, that would indicate there's an integral representation for the L-function just integrating over $H$, which is not expected in the GGP context.

Comment: This sounds like more or less what Paul Nelson actually did, in his work on subconvexity of automorphic $L$-functions for GLn (https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.15230)

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thanks, it seems like the author also mentioned possible generalization in GGP context in page 15, which might not be easy though.